# Configure IPv6 routing

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6, linux-networking

I've got IPv6 addresses from SIXXS. My host is connected with SIXXS network over a AICCU tunnel ("sixxs" interface). My host address is 2001:*::2, the host on the end has address 2001:*::1. On my host IPv6 is fully accessible. 
I have problem with configuring IPv6 network on VMs. I use VirtualBox, the VM (Ubuntu) uses tap1 (on the host bridged by br0)

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

# create a tap
tunctl -t tap1
ip link set up dev tap1

# create the bridge
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 tap1

# set the IP address and routing
ip link set up dev br0
ip -6 route del 2001:6a0:200:172::/64 dev sixxs
ip -6 route add 2001:6a0:200:172::1 dev sixxs
ip -6 addr add 2001:6a0:200:172::2/64 dev br0
ip -6 route add 2001:6a0:200:172::2/64 dev br0
```

Host: routing table:

```
2001:6a0:200:172::1 dev sixxs  metric 1024 
2001:6a0:200:172::/64 dev br0  proto kernel  metric 256 
2001:6a0:200:172::/64 dev br0  metric 1024 
2000::/3 dev sixxs  metric 1024 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev sixxs  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev br0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev tap1  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via 2001:6a0:200:172::1 dev sixxs  metric 1024
```

Guest: interface eth1 (it is connected with tap1):

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet6 static
address 2001:6a0:200:172::3
netmask 64
gateway 2001:6a0:200:172::2
```

Guest: routing table

```
2001:6a0:200:172::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256
default via 2001:6a0:200:172::2 dev eth1 metric 1024
```

The guest pings to the host, the host pings to the guest, the host pings to 2001:6a0:200:172::1, but the guest doesn't ping to 2001:6a0:200:172::1. The guest tries to ping, on the host (by tcdump) I can capture its packets, but the host doesn't send them to 2001:6a0:200:172::1. What have I missed in configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output of the command

```
 sysctl -a | grep ipv6 | grep forward
```

This should show a value of 1 for all the networks you want to forward.  You should be able to enable forwarding with the command:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I would seriously consider setting up an iptables firewall so you don't open your systems entirely to the IPv6 Internet.  Unlike IPv4 you don't have a NAT device preventing inbound connections.  The [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net) firewall has an IPv6 version which should give you a simple to setup firewall.  The example two-interface setup should be a good starting point and can be set to enable forwarding for you.

My article on [Setting up IPv6 on an OpenWRT (Linux) Router](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-6to4-on-openwrt/) may give you some pointers. Configure you hosts as the router.

EDIT: I reviewed SixXS documentation and verified that on the tunnel only the ::1 (P0P and ::2 (your endpoint) addresses are valid.  You should have been provided a 'default routed /64' which you can use on your network.  Assign an address to your bridge.  (Traditionally the ::1 address is the router.)  You may want to configure a `radvd` daemon to announce routes on the internal network.  If you use `radvd` your virtual box image should auto configure with an address and route.

If you want to route other local devices, then add `eth1` or eth0` as appropriate to the bridge.

Comment: Thanks ;) According to your advice I have switched on forwarding, but it hasn't helped me. Still ping gives me "Destination unreachable".

Comment: Thanks ;) Addresses of subnet wasn't correct, also configuring radvd has helped me.

Comment: @BillThor: Uh `echo` with sysctl notation? That won't work. `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` should be better, or `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding` if you want to use echo.